# Iterating from MinValue to MaxValue with overflow

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a simple loop which should look like this

```
for (sbyte i = sbyte.MinValue; i <= sbyte.MaxValue; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

unfortunately `sbyte.MaxValue +1 = sbyte.MinValue` so this never meets the ending condition. My workaround was using `int` from `-128` to `127` but is there also a native `sbyte` approach?

Comment: I think removing that "=" in loop condition should suffice..

Comment: Here is an external link: [Looping Through an Entire Integer Range](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/FullRangeLoop.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not taking into consideration an obvious

> output all except `MaxValue`, then output `MaxValue`

approach, I see one solution.
It works, but looks weird and throws `OverflowException` if `checked` :)

```
sbyte i = sbyte.MinValue;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine(i++);
} while (i != sbyte.MinValue);
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. This code definitely works as it is written now!

Comment: @MatthewWatson It is ok :) Just spent some time trying to figure it out :D

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

```
for (sbyte i = sbyte.MinValue; i <= sbyte.MaxValue; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    if(i==sbyte.MaxValue)
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `int` just for the condition and the `sbyte` inside.

```
int checkVal = sbyte.MinValue;
for (sbyte i = sbyte.MinValue; checkVal <= sbyte.MaxValue; i++, checkVal++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change it to a do...while loop you can get the correct range:

```
sbyte i = sbyte.MinValue;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i++;
}
while(i != sbyte.MaxValue);
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: this returns only up to 126 - i also need `sbyte.MaxValue` (127)

Comment: It needs an additional WriteLine call outside of the loop. I've edited the answer

Comment: a additional `WriteLine` is the ugly way I'd love to avoid

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to use the [`Enumerable.Range(int start, int count)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range) method:

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(sbyte.MinValue, 256))
{
    Console.WriteLine((sbyte)i);
}
```

It's a bit ugly though, because of the magic number 256, and certainly the enumeration is not based on a native `sbyte`.

An even uglier way is to use a `Nullable<sbyte>` as the local loop variable:

```
for (sbyte? i = sbyte.MinValue;
    i.HasValue && i <= sbyte.MaxValue;
    i = unchecked(i < ++i ? i : null))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Not only ugly but slow. So I ended up writing a `Loop` method that accepts inclusive `sbyte` arguments, and can be also called with a negative `step` for backward enumeration:

```
public static void Loop(sbyte fromInclusive, sbyte toInclusive,
    sbyte step, Action<sbyte> action)
{
    var index = fromInclusive;
    while (true)
    {
        action(index);
        sbyte nextIndex = unchecked((sbyte)(index + step));
        if (step > 0)
        {
            if (nextIndex < index) break; // Overflow
            if (nextIndex > toInclusive) break;
        }
        else if (step < 0)
        {
            if (nextIndex > index) break; // Overflow
            if (nextIndex < toInclusive) break;
        }
        index = nextIndex;
    }
}
public static void Loop(sbyte fromInclusive, sbyte toInclusive,
    Action<sbyte> action) => Loop(fromInclusive, toInclusive, 1, action);
```

Usage example:

```
Loop(sbyte.MinValue, sbyte.MaxValue, (i) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
});
```

Output:

> -128
>   -127
>   -126
>   -125
>   -124
>   ...
>   123
>   124
>   125
>   126
>   127

It is slower than a `for` statement with an `int` loop variable, but faster than enumerating an `Enumerable<int>` with `foreach`.